# PHP persistent socket connection

Tags: php, sockets

I have the following architecture.

- A Windows application which can talk with external software through a
  defined port.
- A webapplication running on the same localhost.
- PHP-script serving as connector between these two sides.

I make from the webapplication AJAX-request to php-script which should make connection with the windows application and sent to the webapplication its response.

It works nice.
But only one time.
The second call to php-script already doesn't work because the window application deny access to php-script.
I tryed to use pfsockopen so:

```
if(!isset($fp)) {
    $fp = pfsockopen($address, $service_port, $errno, $errstr, 30);    
}
if(!$fp) die($errstr);

fwrite($fp, $out);
```

But window application deny it when I call it second time. 
What should be the right approach/solution?

Something like let php script runs as a server keeping connection? 
Do you have an idea or example? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like after first time of successful connection you are trying to connect your windows application on same port. Are you changing port number? If you create a persistent connection its likely that windows will keep that port assigned to your first connection. Then it can't use same port for a while. And this explains why it works first time try but not after. Try to use fsockopen instead of persistent one.

Comment: The windows program isn't changing port. And keeps it open after the interaction. So I can connect with it only through the same port.